# Is there a way to create a dashboard in Jupyter Notebook using Python, with graphs that are interactive and other graphs that are static?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, panel

So I'm trying to create a simple panel with 3 graphs, a dropdown menu, and a description for each. However, only one of the graphs is interactive along with its description. The main issue is that the interactive graph is not updating, instead a new graph is being added to the panel thus making the panel longer and longer. The code I have until now is as follows:

```
type hereimport matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import ipywidgets as widgets
from IPython.display import display
import panel as pn
import pandas as pd

# Assume data is your DataFrame containing the required data

# Define graph 1 (no interactivity)
def plot_graph_1(data):
    target_counts = data['Meets end target by completion of project'].value_counts()
    plt.figure(figsize=(8, 6))
    target_counts.plot(kind='bar', color=['green', 'red'])
    plt.title('Projects Meeting End Target by Completion of Project')
    plt.xlabel('Meets End Target')
    plt.ylabel('Number of Projects')
    plt.xticks(rotation=0)
    plt.show()

# Define graph 2 (interactive)
def plot_graph_2(data, selected_sdg):
    sdg_data = data[data['SDG Goal'] == selected_sdg]
    sdg_counts = sdg_data['Meets end target by completion of project'].value_counts()
    yes_color = 'green'
    no_color = 'red'
    plt.figure(figsize=(6, 4))
    sdg_counts[sdg_counts.index.isin(['Yes', 'No'])].reindex(['Yes', 'No']).plot(kind='bar', color=[yes_color, no_color])
    plt.title(f'Meeting End Target by Completion Date for {selected_sdg}')
    plt.xlabel('Meets End Target')
    
    plt.ylabel('Number of Projects')
    plt.xticks(rotation=0)
    plt.show()

# Define dropdown menu for SDG selection
sdg_dropdown = widgets.Dropdown(options=data['SDG Goal'].unique(), description='Select SDG Goal:', disabled=False)

# Define dropdown (interactive)
def dropdown_interactive(data, selected_sdg):
    sdg_data = data[(data['SDG Goal'] == selected_sdg) & (data['Meets end target by completion of project'] == 'No')]
    avg_time = sdg_data['Years until End target is met'].mean()
    print(f"The average time after completion date for projects to meet their End target for SDG {selected_sdg} is: {avg_time:.2f} years")

# Define graph (not interactive)
def plot_graph(data):
    avg_project_length_by_sdg = data.groupby('SDG Goal')['Total Project Length (Years)'].mean().sort_values()
    colors = plt.cm.tab10.colors[:len(avg_project_length_by_sdg)]
    plt.figure(figsize=(10, 6))
    avg_project_length_by_sdg.plot(kind='bar', color=colors)
    plt.title('Average Time to reach SDG Goal')
    plt.xlabel('SDG Goal')
    plt.ylabel('Average Total Project Length (Years)')
    plt.xticks(rotation=45)
    plt.show()

# Define dropdown (interactive)
def dropdown_interactive2(data, selected_sdg):
    sdg_data = data[data['SDG Goal'] == selected_sdg]
    avg_project_length = sdg_data['Total Project Length (Years)'].mean()
    print(f"The average total time for SDG {selected_sdg} to be met is: {avg_project_length:.2f} years")

# Display the dropdown menu and observe changes
display(sdg_dropdown)

# Create Panel objects for each component
plot1_panel = pn.bind(plot_graph_1, data)
plot2_panel = pn.bind(plot_graph_2, data, sdg_dropdown)
dropdown_interactive_panel = pn.bind(dropdown_interactive, data, sdg_dropdown)
plot_graph_panel = pn.bind(plot_graph, data)
dropdown_interactive2_panel = pn.bind(dropdown_interactive2, data, sdg_dropdown)

# Define the layout for the dashboard
top_row = pn.Row(
    plot2_panel,
    dropdown_interactive_panel
)

bottom_row = pn.Row(
    plot1_panel,
    plot_graph_panel
)

# Combine all components into a single dashboard layout
dashboard = pn.Column(
    '# Dashboard Title',
    top_row,
    bottom_row
)

# Show the dashboard
dashboard.show()
```

Only graph 2 along with the defined dropdown should be updating, however they are being added once again. If any more context such as pictures or a quick video to showcase what is happening is needed, please do let me know. Thank you.

I tried by doing it part by part, specifically graph 2 along with the specific descriptions and the dropdown menu, and that way it worked. However, when I started adding the static graphs everything started breaking down.

Comment: "# Assume data is your DataFrame containing the required data" It is easy to share data these days even if it is toy data. See 'Help others reproduce the problem' in [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). The answer to "Is there a way to create a dashboard in Jupyter Notebook using Python, with graphs that are interactive and other graphs that are static?" is 'yes'. I'm more familiar with Voila than panel. In Voila you make separate cells and so essentially when you activate the Voila view, i.e., dashboard, it is essentially the same as the output of the...

Comment: <continued> notebook **without the input cells showing**. See about [Voila here](https://github.com/voila-dashboards/voila). There's an entire gallery of examples linked there if you scroll down there, to find mention of [The Voila Gallery](https://github.com/voila-dashboards/voila#the-voil%C3%A0-gallery). You seem to show no cell breaks in your code.

Comment: @Wayne Thanks for your helpful response, I will try with Voila.

Comment: MyBinder is good for developing these without needing to install on your system if you want to play around without committing yet. I have a whole bunch of examples [here in this repo](https://github.com/fomightez/communication_voila) which different URLs that trigger opening sessions in different modes. Also [here](https://github.com/fomightez/3Dscatter_plot-binder) has an example that builds towards making a feature-rich UI in the later notebooks available in the session that launches, although it is only one plot in that example. All that was developed without installing Voila locally.